# DCOS with IPv6 only

Tags: dcos

I am installing DCOS ver 1.8.7 on CentOS7 using IPv6 networks in CLI mode, getting following bold error --

```
[root@dcos-bootstrap centos]# ./dcos_generate_config.sh --genconf
====> EXECUTING CONFIGURATION GENERATION
Generating configuration files...
```

**master_list: Invalid IPv4 addresses in list: 2001:1b76:2400:e2:f816:3eff:fe46:ab05**

Config options I am using --

```
---
agent_list:
- "2001:1b76:2400:e2:f816:3eff:feb5:c081"
bootstrap_url: file:///opt/dcos_install_tmp
cluster_name: crazy
exhibitor_storage_backend: static
master_discovery: static
master_list:
- "2001:1b76:2400:e2:f816:3eff:fe46:ab05"
public_agent_list:
- "2001:1b76:2400:e2:f816:3eff:feb5:c081"
resolvers:
- 8.8.8.8
- 8.8.4.4
ssh_port: 22
ssh_user: root
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

One of the core component of DC/OS is [Apache Mesos](http://mesos.apache.org/), which currently does not support IPv6, but it is [in the works](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-1027). As a consequence, DC/OS does not support IPv6 currently.